# Why cant the metadata be stored in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Why cant the metadata be stored in HDFS with 3 replication. Why does it store in the local disk?

Answer (score 1):

Because it will take more time to name node in resource allocation due to several I/o operations. So it's better to store metadata in memory of name node.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reason

1. If it stored on HDFS, there will be network I/O. which will be
   slower.
2. Name-node will have dependency on data node for metadata.
3. Again Metadata will be require for metadata to Name-node, So that it can identify where the metadata is on hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

METADATA is the data about the data such as where the block is stored in rack, so that it can be located and if metadata is stored in hdfs and if those datanodes fail's you will lose all your data because now you don't know how to access those blocks where your data was stored.

Even though if you keep replication factor more, for each changes in datanodes, the changes are made in replicas of data nodes as well as in namenode's edit log.

> Now since we have 3 replicas of namenodes for every change in datanode it first have to change in
>
> 1.Its own replica blocks
>
> 2. In namenode and replicas of namenode.(edit_log is edited 3times )

This would cause to write more data than first.But data storage is not the only and major problem,the main problem is the time that is required to do all these operations.

Therefore namenodes are backup on remote disk,so that even though your whole clusters get fails(possibilities are less) you can always backup your data.

> To save from namenode failure Hadoop comes with
>
> Primary Namenode  ->consisits of namespace image and edit logs.
>
> Secondary Namenode -> merging namespace and editlogs so that edit logs dont become too large.